# MongoDB "GET API" Returning Empty Array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend

I am trying to fetch data from mongodb altes, I have uploaded 5 collections which is working absolutely fine but as soon as I'm trying to upload new Api it is showing fine (status fine) but as soon as I try to check it through postman ..it shows "[]" empty;
what could be reason;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBb61.png)

Answer (score 0):

few days back I had put out question, so I got the answer ....

if you are able to post Api from postman and getting inside the mongodb atles , but when you post the data "Manually" and when you check in the postman and coming empty, then you have to make post req route as you have made get reoute, And post through postman instead of posting manually on mongodb atles....then you will be successfully getting back Api from APi.